# How are the weights updated in this code?

Tags: tensorflow, logistic-regression

I am reading this code, but can't figure out how the weights get updated in its logic:

```
tf.enable_eager_execution()

x = np.arange(0, 5, 0.1)
y = x**3 - 4*x**2 - 2*x + 2
y_noise = y + np.random.normal(0, 1.5, size=(len(x),))

def get_batch(x, y, batch_size=20):
    idxs = np.random.randint(0, len(x), (batch_size))
    return x[idxs], y[idxs]


class PolyModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.w = tfe.Variable(tf.random_normal([4]))

    def f(self, x):
        return self.w[0] * x ** 3 + self.w[1] * x ** 2 + self.w[2] * x + self.w[3]


def loss(model, x, y):
    err = model.f(x) - y
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(err))

model = PolyModel()
grad = tfe.implicit_gradients(loss)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
iters = 20000
for i in range(iters):
    x_batch, y_batch = get_batch(x, y)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(grad(model, x_batch, y_batch))
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        print("Iteration {}, loss: {}".format(i+1, loss(model, x_batch, y_batch).numpy()))
```

Is that because in this line, the weights are updated implicitly in the function "apply_gradients"?

```
 optimizer.apply_gradients(grad(model, x_batch, y_batch))
```

Answer (score 0):

`tfe.implicit_gradients(loss)` is a function that  calculates the gradient of the `loss` with respect to model weights. `optimizer.apply_gradients()` apply the gradients i.e., it updates the weights according to the update rule for the optimizer used (for example the update will vary between 'Adam' and 'SGD'). So at each iteration the model weights are updated.

Comment: grad(model, x_batch, y_batch) --- is 'grad' a function here? Should it be a scalar or vector?

Comment: it is a function, after you call it returns gradient is with respect to all trainable variables.

Comment: So, "tfe.implicit_gradients(loss)" return the function "grad", which then make the call "grad(model, x_batch, y_batch)"? In my PyCharm I can't not check the implementation of implicit_gradient.